# Error: "No gradients provided for any variable" while using custom loss

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, tf.keras, gradienttape

When I am using custom loss function with batch gradient descent. I am getting error give in photos below after first epoch.
The code runs fine with binaryCrossEntropy.

I am getting the error below:

```
optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model_2.trainable_weights))

No gradients provided for any variable: (['dense_22/kernel:0', 'dense_22/bias:0', 'dense_23/kernel:0', 'dense_23/bias:0', 'dense_24/kernel:0', 'dense_24/bias:0'],).
```

The code:

```py
# importing necessary libraries and functions
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model, load_model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import InputLayer, GlobalAveragePooling2D, Dense, Dropout
from tensorflow.keras.applications.densenet import DenseNet121, preprocess_input
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras.losses import CategoricalCrossentropy
from tensorflow.keras.metrics import Mean, CategoricalAccuracy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import keras.backend as K
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
from collections import deque
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split       #train test split
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold        #Stratifying the data (for test train split)
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler             #data normalization with sklearn
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


import math

lambda_par = tf.Variable(0.5)

def fairnessLoss(y_true,y_pred):
  print("HI",y_true,y_pred)
  cse_min = cse_maj = tf.Variable(0.0)
  n_min = n_maj = tf.Variable(0.0)
  print(y_pred.shape[0])
  for i in range(y_pred.shape[0]):
    print(i)
    if(y_true[i][0]==1):
      cse_min.assign_add(tf.math.log(y_pred[i][0]))
      n_min.assign_add(1.0)
    else:
      cse_maj.assign_add(tf.math.log(1-y_pred[i][0]))
      n_maj.assign_add(1.0)
  print("First step")
  tem1 = tf.divide(cse_min,n_min)
  tem2 = tf.divide(cse_maj,n_maj)
  fe = tf.Variable(tem1)
  fe.assign_add(-tem2)
  fe = tf.math.multiply(fe,fe)
  ans = tf.Variable(0.0)
  ans.assign_add(cse_min)
  ans.assign_add(cse_maj)
  ans.assign_add(tf.math.multiply(lambda_par,fe))
  return ans

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(8, activation=tf.keras.activations.sigmoid), # hidden layer 1, ReLU activation
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(8, activation=tf.keras.activations.sigmoid),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation=tf.keras.activations.sigmoid)
])


batch_size=len(train_X)
train_yy = []
for i in range(len(train_y)):
  train_yy.append([train_y[i]])
train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((train_X, train_yy))
train_dataset = train_dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=1024).batch(batch_size)

# # Prepare the validation dataset.
# val_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_val, y_val))
# val_dataset = val_dataset.batch(batch_size)


train_acc_metric = keras.metrics.BinaryAccuracy()
val_acc_metric = keras.metrics.BinaryAccuracy()

epochs = 500
# Instantiate an optimizer to train the model.
optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam()
# Instantiate a loss function.
loss_fn = keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True)
# storing variables to plot loss and accuracy
losses = []
accuracy = []
for epoch in range(epochs):
    print("\nStart of epoch %d" % (epoch,))
    epoch_loss_avg = Mean()

    # Iterate over the batches of the dataset.
    for step, (x_batch_train, y_batch_train) in enumerate(train_dataset):[
        # Open a GradientTape to record the operations run
        # during the forward pass, which enables auto-differentiation.
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:

            # Run the forward pass of the layer.
            # The operations that the layer applies
            # to its inputs are going to be recorded
            # on the GradientTape.
            logits = model(x_batch_train, training=True)  # Logits for this minibatch

            # Compute the loss value for this minibatch.
            loss_value = fairnessLoss(y_batch_train, logits)

        # Use the gradient tape to automatically retrieve
        # the gradients of the trainable variables with respect to the loss.
        grads = tape.gradient(loss_value, model.trainable_weights)

        # Run one step of gradient descent by updating
        # the value of the variables to minimize the loss.
        optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model.trainable_weights))

        epoch_loss_avg.update_state(loss_value)

        train_acc_metric.update_state(y_batch_train, logits)

        losses.append(epoch_loss_avg.result())
        accuracy.append(train_acc_metric.result())

        # Log every 200 batches.
        if step % 200 == 0:
            print(
                "Training loss (for one batch) at step %d: %.4f"
                % (step, float(loss_value))
            )
            print("Seen so far: %s samples" % ((step + 1) * batch_size))
    print(train_acc_metric.result())
    
    train_acc_metric.reset_states()
```

[Photo of the error-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uPi5Q.png)

[Photo of the error-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ckgi.png)

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: The way this loss is implemented makes it non-differentiable, I would not use assign_add at all.

Answer (score 0):

Loads and Optimizers are dual parallel in the statistics, accelerate to hear the Optimizers or vary their rates to see the true.

Sample: Gradient Tape when applying value to tf.variables, loss functions is what change or apply, and measurement from you provided logics but optimizers are how you achieved it or setting to goals.

Dataset: Image categories problem, image, and labels for categories.

```
Index    Image                                             Label

1   F:\datasets\downloads\Actors\train\Candidt Kibt\01.tif  0
2   F:\datasets\downloads\Actors\train\Candidt Kibt\02.tif  0
19  F:\datasets\downloads\Actors\train\Pikaploy\01.tif      1
```

Codes: For test Tape and Gradients only

```
import os
from os.path import exists

import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
[PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:GPU:0', device_type='GPU')]
None
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
physical_devices = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
assert len(physical_devices) > 0, "Not enough GPU hardware devices available"
config = tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(physical_devices[0], True)
print(physical_devices)
print(config)

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Variables
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
num_iter = 1000
train_generator_batch_size = 1
batch_size = 1
WIDTH = 256
HEIGHT = 256
CHANNEL = 3

checkpoint_path = "F:\\models\\checkpoint\\" + os.path.basename(__file__).split('.')[0] + "\\TF_DataSets_01.h5"
checkpoint_dir = os.path.dirname(checkpoint_path)

if not exists(checkpoint_dir) : 
    os.mkdir(checkpoint_dir)
    print("Create directory: " + checkpoint_dir)

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Definition / Class
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
def create_image_generator( ):
    variables = pd.read_excel('F:\\temp\\Python\\excel\\Book 7.xlsx', index_col=None, header=[0], dtype=str)
    
    train_generator = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(
        rescale=1./255,
        shear_range=0.2,
        zoom_range=0.2,
        horizontal_flip=True,
        
        validation_split=0.2,
    
    )

    train_image_ds = train_generator.flow_from_dataframe(
        dataframe = variables,
        directory=None,
        x_col= 'Image',
        y_col= 'Label',
        weight_col=None,
        target_size=( WIDTH, HEIGHT ),
        color_mode='rgb',
        classes=None,
        class_mode='categorical',           ####
        batch_size=train_generator_batch_size,
        shuffle=True,
        seed=None,
        save_to_dir=None,
        save_prefix='',
        save_format='png',
        subset=None,
        interpolation='nearest',
        validate_filenames=True,
    )

    return train_image_ds

class gradient_tape_optimizer( ):
    def __init__ ( self, model, num_iter, content_iter, batch_size ):
        
        self.num_iter = num_iter
        self.content_iter = content_iter
        self.style_iter = content_iter 
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.model = model
        self.loss = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy( from_logits=False, 
            reduction=tf.keras.losses.Reduction.AUTO, 
            name='sparse_categorical_crossentropy' )
            
        self.optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Nadam( learning_rate=0.00001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-07, name='Nadam' )

    def _compute_mean_std( self, feats : tf.Tensor, eps=1e-8 ):
        """
        feats: Features should be in shape N x H x W x C
        """
        mean = tf.math.reduce_mean(feats, axis=[1,2], keepdims=True)
        std = tf.math.reduce_std(feats, axis=[1,2], keepdims=True) + eps
        return mean, std

    def criterion( self, stylized_img : tf.Tensor, style_img : tf.Tensor, t : tf.Tensor ):
        stylized_content_feats = self.model.encode(stylized_img)
        stylized_feats = self.model.encode(stylized_img, return_all=True)
        style_feats = self.model.encode(style_img, return_all=True)

        content_loss = self.mse_loss(t, stylized_content_feats)

        style_loss = 0
        for f1, f2 in zip(stylized_feats, style_feats):
            m1, s1 = self._compute_mean_std(f1)
            m2, s2 = self._compute_mean_std(f2)
            style_loss += self.mse_loss(m1, m2) + self.mse_loss(s1, s2)

        return content_loss + self.style_weight * style_loss

    def train( self ):
        step = 0
        while step < self.num_iter:
            content_batch = self.content_iter.get_next()

            if content_batch[0].shape[1] != self.batch_size:
                content_batch = self.content_iter.get_next()

            style_batch = self.style_iter.get_next()
            
            if style_batch[0].shape[1] != self.batch_size:
                style_batch = self.style_iter.get_next()
            
            
            current_label = tf.constant( content_batch[1], shape=( 2, 1 ) ).numpy()
            loss_value = tf.Variable( 10.0 )
            
            with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
                
                result = self.model( inputs=tf.constant( content_batch[0], shape=( 1, WIDTH, HEIGHT, CHANNEL ) ) )
                result = tf.constant( result, shape=( 2, 1 ) )

                predict_label = tf.Variable( tf.constant( self.model.trainable_weights[len(self.model.trainable_weights) - 1], shape=( 2, 1 ) ) )
                loss_value =  self.loss( result.numpy(), current_label )
                loss_value =  tf.Variable( tf.constant( loss_value, shape=( 1, ) ).numpy() )
                tape.watch( loss_value )
            
            gradients = tape.gradient( loss_value, loss_value )

            self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, self.model.trainable_weights))

            # log and save every 200 batches
            if step % 200 == 0:
            
                if result[tf.math.argmax(result).numpy()[0]][0] > 0 :
                    print(f'Training loss (for one batch) at step {step}: {self.loss} value {result[tf.math.argmax(result).numpy()[0]]}')
                else :  
                    print(f'Training loss (for one batch) at step {step}: {self.loss} value {result[abs( 1 - tf.math.argmax(result).numpy()[0]) ]}')
                    
                print(f'Seen so far: {(step+1)*self.batch_size} samples')

                self.model.save_weights(checkpoint_path)

            step += 1

        print("Finished training...")
        self.model.save_weights(checkpoint_path)

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Dataset
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
variables = pd.read_excel('F:\\temp\\Python\\excel\\Book 7.xlsx', index_col=None, header=[0], dtype=str)

train_image_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
    create_image_generator,
    output_types=None,
    output_shapes=None,
    args=None,

    output_signature=(
        tf.TensorSpec(shape=( 1, WIDTH, HEIGHT, CHANNEL ), dtype=tf.float32, name=None), tf.TensorSpec(shape=(1, 2), dtype=tf.float32, name=None),
        ),
    
    name='train_image_ds'
)

train_image_ds = train_image_ds.batch( 1 )
iterator = iter( train_image_ds )

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Model Initialize
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=( WIDTH, HEIGHT, CHANNEL )),
    tf.keras.layers.Normalization(mean=3., variance=2.),
    tf.keras.layers.Normalization(mean=4., variance=6.),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Reshape((128, 127 * 127)),
    tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(96, return_sequences=True, return_state=False)),
    tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(96)),
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(192, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(2),
])

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Optimizer
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Nadam(
    learning_rate=0.00001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=0.0000001,
    name='Nadam'
)

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Loss Fn
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""                               
lossfn = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(
    from_logits=False,
    reduction=tf.keras.losses.Reduction.AUTO,
    name='sparse_categorical_crossentropy'
)

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Model Summary
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=lossfn, metrics=['accuracy'])

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Training
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
gradient_tape_optimizer = gradient_tape_optimizer( model, num_iter, iterator, batch_size )
result = gradient_tape_optimizer.train()

input( '...' )
```

Result: Loss is change less that is because custom Optimizers is simply algorithms.

```
2022-10-15 14:23:57.141863: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:384] Loaded cuDNN version 8100
Training loss (for one batch) at step 0: <keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy object at 0x00000238B5054550> value [0.06285592]
Seen so far: 1 samples
Training loss (for one batch) at step 200: <keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy object at 0x00000238B5054550> value [0.05492945]
Seen so far: 201 samples
Training loss (for one batch) at step 400: <keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy object at 0x00000238B5054550> value [0.05577546]
Seen so far: 401 samples
Training loss (for one batch) at step 600: <keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy object at 0x00000238B5054550> value [0.06180618]
Seen so far: 601 samples
Training loss (for one batch) at step 800: <keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy object at 0x00000238B5054550> value [0.05990243]
Seen so far: 801 samples
Finished training...
...
```

Comment: This is yet another answer that does not make any sense and does not answer the question asked, this code does not even have a custom loss.